# Confused adding header files in ROS2

Tags: ros, ros2, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the migration tutorial : [LINK](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Migration-Guide/)

It is obvious that I need to specify a subfolder msg and replace .h to .hpp.

However, I can see some different situation with ROS2 tf2 package: [LINK](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2)
It seems that I need to add the `<tf2/LinearMath/Quaternion.h>` as in ROS1 like this:

```
#include "tf2/LinearMath/Quaternion.h"
```

Can someone suggest me the correct way of including this header file in ROS2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308882/confused-adding-header-files-in-ros2/) by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 361 on 2018-11-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a `geometry_msgs/msg/quaternion.hpp` that is the replacement of `geometry_msgs/Quaternion.h` in ros1. `tf2/LinearMath/Quaternion.h` is not a message, it doesn't have a changed path or capitalization or extension (yet?) from ros1 to ros2 so the same include will work.  This http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Quaternions#Components_of_a_quaternion still applies:

> ROS uses two quaternion datatypes: msg and 'tf.' To convert between them in C++, use the methods of tf/transform_datatypes.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0